# Como remover acentos no R?

Tags: string, r

Como remover de maneira eficiente os acentos e til no R?
O que eu quero é fazer de uma maneira mais prática do que especificar a substituição letra por letra.

```
estados=c("São Paulo","Paraíba","Espírito Santo")

estados <- sub("ã","a",estados)
estados <- sub("í","i",estados)
estados <- sub("í","i",estados)
estados

[1] "Sao Paulo"      "Paraiba"        "Espirito Santo"
```